# JavaScript breadth-first search algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6, breadth-first-search

I have implemented a breadth-first search and I'm more or less looking for suggestions on how I can improve on what I've done here.

How to use:

```
search(queue, "Musician");
```

The logs from the search:

> ```
> Lansana is not a Musician. Lansana is a Software Engineer.
> Zack is not a Musician. Zack is a Software Architect.
> John is not a Musician. John is a Project Manager.
> Francisco is not a Musician. Francisco is a Game Developer.
> Ronaldinho is not a Musician. Ronaldinho is a Professional Soccer Player.
> Lauren is not a Musician. Lauren is a Mango Seller.
> Angelica is not a Musician. Angelica is a Professional Volleyball Player.
> Cody is not a Musician. Cody is a Network Programmer.
> Match found: Beyonce is a Musician!
> ```

I believe it works correctly because if you look at the order in which I enqueue people, and the order in which their `friends` are enqueued, you'll notice that the logs match the exact order (which of course is crucial in this algorithm in order to get the shortest path).

```js
class Queue {
    constructor() {
        this.count = 0;
        this.data = {};
    }

    enqueue(key, val) {
        if (!this.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this.count++;
        }
        this.data[key] = val;
    }

    dequeue() {
        let key = Object.keys(this.data)[0],
            memo = this.data[key];
        delete this.data[key];
        this.count--;
        return memo;
    }
}

class Person {
    constructor(args) {
        this.name = args.name;
        this.friends = args.friends || [];
        this.profession = args.profession;
    }
}

let Ronaldinho = new Person({
        name: "Ronaldinho",
        profession: "Professional Soccer Player"
    }),
    Lauren = new Person({
        name: "Lauren",
        profession: "Mango Seller"
    }),
    Angelica = new Person({
        name: "Angelica",
        profession: "Professional Volleyball Player"
    }),
    Cody = new Person({
        name: "Cody",
        profession: "Network Programmer"
    }),
    Beyonce = new Person({
        name: "Beyonce",
        profession: "Musician"
    }),
    Lansana = new Person({
        name: "Lansana",
        friends: [Ronaldinho, Lauren, Angelica],
        profession: "Software Engineer"
    }),
    Zack = new Person({
        name: "Zack",
        friends: [Cody],
        profession: "Software Architect"
    }),
    John = new Person({
        name: "John",
        friends: [Ronaldinho, Angelica],
        profession: "Project Manager"
    }),
    Francisco = new Person({
        name: "Francisco",
        friends: [Beyonce],
        profession: "Game Developer"
    });

let queue = new Queue();

queue.enqueue("Lansana", Lansana);
queue.enqueue("Zack", Zack);
queue.enqueue("John", John);
queue.enqueue("Francisco", Francisco);

function search(queue, profession) {
    let searched = [];

    while (queue.count > 0) {
        let person = queue.dequeue();

        if (!searched[person.name]) {
            if (hasProfession(person, profession)) {
                console.log(`Match found: ${person.name} is  a ${person.profession}!`);
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log(`${person.name} is not a ${profession}. ${person.name} is a ${person.profession}.`);
                for(let i = 0, len = person.friends.length; i < len; i++) {
                    queue.enqueue(person.friends[i].name, person.friends[i]);
                }
            }

            searched.push(person.name);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function hasProfession(person, profession) {
    return person.profession.toLowerCase() === profession.toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just going to make a few comment on your `Queue` implementation.

> Should your data be an object `this.data = {};`?

This is a matter of taste, but I would have opted for an `array` or a `linkedlist` data structure if I were you. Using an array, you can easily `push` items without a key . From my perspective ,you are basically passing the same name for the *key/value* pair in the `enqueue`.

> How to retrieve the total number of items enqueued?

I believe your class should  `data` should only be private to your class. hence the data count should be accessed using a `getter` function e.g

```
this.count = function() {
    return this.data.length;
  };
```

> What should your `enqueue` look like?

basically, your `Queue` class is not reusable as it's dependent on having *key/value* pair has an input. I reckon the `enqueue` function should take only one value .  In this case `John`. A pseudocode

```js
    enqueue(value) {
      // created an empty if statement - note if value is undefined this will evaluate to true as well as null ==null
      if (value == null);
      else {
        if ( //data enqueued has exceeded the current array length) {
          let newcapacity = Math.floor(this.count() * this.growfactor / 100);
          // create a new array with the capacity and copy the old array elements to a new one.
        }

        this.size++;
        // assign the item to an empty index 
        this.data[index] = value;
      }
    }
    }
```

Although, the above is more or less a C# equivalent but the main idea is you only `enqueue` items when they are not null/undefined - hence I used `==` as opposed to `===` as `undefined== null` results in true and `null==null` results in true . This is equivalent to

```
if ( typeof(some_variable) !== "undefined" && some_variable !== null ) {}
```

The `newCapacity` is simply a strategy to increase the `size` of an array.

> How to easily delete an item using an `array`?

Constantly, you need to check if your array's size is zero then `throw` an exception else call the array's `shift()` function to delete the first item and update the array.

```
dequeue() {
  if (size === 0) {
    throw "the queue contains no items";
  }
  this.data.shift();
}
```

> Note: there are some very useful `Queue` functions that can be added to your class :

- **peek()** : returns the first item in the queue
- **contains** : Check if an item exist
- **isempty()**- checks if an item is empty

I hope this helps.